# Configuration of Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-code

So recently I started switching from sublime text 3 to Visual Studio Code, and there are a few things which bother me, so I was wondering if its possible to change/configure this:

1. When selecting "*Open with Visual Studio Code*" from the Windows Explorer on a file which is already opened, visual studio will still reopen the file in a new window.
2. For my C++ code, some inline method definitions are in files ending with `.I` (I am unable to change this). I already configured VS Code to detect those as C++ files, however <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> does not switch between the `.I` and `.h` / `.cpp` file. (It does fine between `.h`/`.cpp`)
3. Is there something like a hex view for binary files? Right now I am unable to edit them with VS Code.
4. <strike>I added some files to my exclude list in `search.exclude` and `files.watcherExclude`. Those are properly ignored in the quick-change bar, but they are still shown in the file-hierarchy on the left. Is it possible to hide them there as well?</strike> **Found it: its `files.exclude`**
5. When creating and saving a new file, the save dialog always starts at the project directory. Is it possible to change this, so that it defaults to the path of the last-opened file, just like in sublime text?
6. Is there an option/extension to have a code-minimap next to the scrollbar, like in sublime text?

Comment: Read the FAQ. Here is more about some config: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization/userandworkspace

Comment: I did read the FAQ, it covers not a single one of my questions, except I do miss something?

Comment: Also, I already checked the config, but did not find the parameters I was looking for, which is why I am asking.

Comment: about the minimap: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/7752789-minimap

Answer (score 0):

Regarding 6.)

put something like this in your settings.json:

```
"editor.minimap.enabled": true,
"editor.minimap.maxColumn": 200,
"editor.minimap.renderCharacters": false
```